# WooCommerce: tax price filter not being applied in admin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, tax

I've implemented a filter as per [this WooCommerce article on taxes](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/How-Taxes-Work-in-WooCommerce#prices-including-tax---experimental-behavior):

`add_filter('woocommerce_adjust_non_base_location_prices', '__return_false');`

This effectively 'ignores' tax rates on checkout: an €8,99 product (where prices are added inclusive of tax) being sold from a UK store will cost €8,99 to a German customer, a French customer or an ROI customer. This all works fine on the front end.

However, I just created an order in the backend for a German customer, and that €8,99 product is being added to the order at €7,49 with no tax. I understand from a tax perspective why this is happening (a UK store selling in Germany *shouldn't* apply tax, so 8.99 - 20% UK VAT = 7.49), however this seems to be ignoring my `woocommerce_adjust_non_base_location_prices` filter.

At the moment my filter call is just a single line in a custom plugin, so being implemented at `plugins_loaded`, I guess. There's no condition for it (e.g. `if (!is_admin()) {}`), so I'm wondering if I need some other kind of condition to ensure it *is* applied to admin orders, or if I'm looking at a bug?

Comment: Hey, did you find solution for this issue?

Comment: @FadiNouh I had to remind myself of the issue, but the short answer is: no. The client never finalised their German site, so I didn't do any more work on it. I did open it as a ticket (https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/pull/19109) and apparently it was fixed and merged into core in version `3.4.0`, but I've not looked at it to test.